# Second for loop is not being executed

Tags: c++, loops

I am solving one competitive programming problem where I'm trying to traverse an array in reverse and inside it again traverse it in reverse direction. I've included this snippet from my code which doesn't seem to be working. The second loop is just ignored. It just outputs:

loop3

loop2

loop1

```
for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
{
    cout<<"loop"<<i<<endl;
    int a=arr[i];
    int cnt=0;
    if(!checked[a]) continue;
    checked[a]=1;
    int kk=k;

    for(int j=i;j>=0;j--)
    {
        cout<<"in second loop";
        int b=arr[j];
        int res=a-b;
        if(res<=kk)
        {
            kk-=res;
            cnt++;
            continue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: probably because `if(!checked[a]) continue;` is always true

Comment: Yeah, you got it correct. Thanks!

Comment: Ahah i'm a wizard

Comment: *I am solving one competitive programming* -- Given the issue and what the solution is, you should invest more time in "competitive debugging", where you have a broken program and the contest is to fix it.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I really like it when people here sarcastically correct you and even provide the solution! Thanks @PaulMcKenzie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(!checked[a]) continue;
checked[a] = 1;
```

You might mean

```
if(checked[a]) continue;
checked[a] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive that checked is an array of zeros at the start of the for loop, if thats the case your if statment shoud be

```
if(checked[a]) continue;
```

Without the '!'.